# How can a political campaign obtain my personal data?

Tags: united-states, civil-rights, data-sources, privacy, voter-registration

A campaign volunteer contacted me about my voting choices for this November election... which wouldn’t be noteworthy hadn’t he addressed me by my wife’s name.

When I asked about how they had associated that name with that phone number, I was told that that’s the information they got from the public voter registration list (which is not the case as when we registered, at different times and places, we both provided our own phone numbers).

When I asked more about it, he told me he was a volunteer and couldn’t give me that information. And when I insisted, I got a non-existing email address (possibly just a typo) to inquiry.

I know my phone number is associated with my wife’s name in some places (children school, doctor’s office) because my work schedule is more flexible and allows me to answer in case something happens, but definitely not in her voter registration (as she registered before meeting me).

How could a political campaign get that data association? Do I have the right to know the real source of my personal data?

Comment: AFAIK, phone numbers aren't private. Regardless, this isn't a politics question.

Comment: @blip I was doubting about asking  here or in the Law site, I finally decided to put it here as it’s related to a political campaign and their data sources (although I can see how it’s a blurry thing). About the question itself, the issue is not that they contacted me (something almost expected during campaign periods) but that they contacted me thinking I was another person (related to me) and, when asked about it, they didn’t give an honest answer about their sources. Maybe I could rewrite the question to focus more on campaign data sources and if voters are allowed to review them.

Comment: Perhaps. But in the end, it's all marketing. Whether they're selling a candidate, or time shares. I'm not sure if there's anything unique in terms of figuring out your voters.

Comment: I would expect political campaigns to be subject to different regulations (electoral codes and laws) distinct to the ones that apply to a company selling time shares.

Comment: Although I think this question would be on topic for this site (it's a real problem related to a political process or campaign), if it could fit better in [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/), I'd be open to migrate it.

Comment: Asking if campaigns are restricted with a different set of consumer data protections laws than business in general is an interesting question, but yes, perhaps more appropriate for the law site.

Comment: @Philipp could you migrate the question to Law Stack Exchange?

Comment: @blip - time shares constitute less of a rip-off/fraud.

Comment: For those browsing before this question is migrated: Most, if not all, states allow political campaigns, scholars, and journalists access to voter registration information for non-commercial purposes; it's how campaigns know who to send their mail to. (What party you register for and whether you voted in a given election (but not how) may also be public.) From there it's possible to merge that information with other public and marketing data, such as who one is married to.

Comment: @user4012 ha! True.

Answer (score 1):

If the information trail to you starts with your registering to vote, or with anything that involves you giving your address to any semi-established organization, then this trail can be re-established with mail forwarding.  The senders of the mail are notified whenever mail is forwarded (due to a move).  This process of changing internal records to forwarded addresses (based on information provided by the postal service) has become automated in the recent years.  It's entirely possible (even likely) that the volunteer simply didn't know about it (because it's a technical detail and he was simply manning a phone).